# need sudo in cronjob ubuntu server sending out logwatch file

Tags: bash, logwatch

I have logwatch configured on ubuntu server to creat html file in /tmp/logwatch.html

I also installed sendEmail smpt sender.

I-m trying to use sendEmail like this:

```
sendEmail -v -f username@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu username -xp xxxpassword -t mymail -o tls=yes -u Security Audit -m logwatch Reports -a /tmp/logwatch.html
```

It gives me error cannot find file, obviously because logwatch.html is created with 600 permission.

If I do it with sudo it works and I recieve mail correctly.

Problem is that I need to create bash script and cron it.

Bit sudo inside bash won't work right? what would you do in my place? I'd prefere a simple solution.

1. Make logwatch write file and set permission 666. But I cannot find this option.
2. Write sudo in bash file, but how do i pass password?
3. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a cron job as root, you don't need to use `sudo` every time the script runs.

Just add it to the root's crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: didn't know there were 2 crontabs, I tried sudo and without and I see two different files. Thanks.